# Why when I make a change in the Js file the local server stopped when it's running?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Why when I run npm run dev and make any changes in the Js file the local server stopped when it's running and that's happened for windows os only I tried that for Linux and works fine.
it gives me the next error :

```
C:\Users\osama\OneDrive\Desktop\calculator workflow\scripts\development.js:66
                                if (err) throw err;
                                         ^

[Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile 'C:\Users\osama\OneDrive\Desktop\calculator workflow\src\scripts\main.js' -> 'C:\Users\osama\OneDrive\Desktop\calculator workflow\.tmp'] {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'copyfile',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\osama\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\calculator workflow\\src\\scripts\\main.js',
  dest: 'C:\\Users\\osama\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\calculator workflow\\.tmp'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `node ./scripts/task-runner/tasks.js serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\osama\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-23T16_47_01_115Z-debug.log
```

and this is the log file :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\osama\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.11
3 info using node@v14.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
6 info lifecycle @~dev: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: C:\Users\osama\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\osama\OneDrive\Desktop\calculator workflow\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\osama\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet;C:\Program Files\nodejs;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Users\osama\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\osama\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\osama\AppData\Local\hyper\app-3.0.2\resources\bin;C:\Users\osama\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: C:\Users\osama\OneDrive\Desktop\calculator workflow
10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node ./scripts/task-runner/tasks.js serve' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `node ./scripts/task-runner/tasks.js serve`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\osama\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\osama\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\osama\OneDrive\Desktop\calculator workflow
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22000
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\osama\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v14.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.11
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ dev: `node ./scripts/task-runner/tasks.js serve`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I didn't understand why this happen in windows only and works fine for Linux with track changes and the server never stopped.